# How to run ChkDsk on Storage Spaces which is stuck in read only mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, storage, storage-spaces

I am having a number of issues with Storage Spaces which began when a drive died. I have 5 WD Reds in Parity. I have not replaced the disk but the drive refuses to come in to Read / Write mode and complains of critical write errors.

The physical disks are okay. I ran hardware checks on them for 12 hours.

In Event Viewer after an unsuccessful mount operation I can see a number of NTFS errors:

> {Delayed Write Failed} Windows was unable to save all the data for the
>   file . The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure
>   of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save
>   this file elsewhere.
>
> The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may
>   occur in VolumeId: S:, DeviceName: \Device\HarddiskVolume15. (A device
>   which does not exist was specified.)
>
> The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may
>   occur in VolumeId: S:, DeviceName: \Device\HarddiskVolume15. (A device
>   which does not exist was specified.)

I can mount the volume in Read Only mode but then I am unable to try and run Check Disk. Is there anyway I can force it to to run a Check Disk?

Repair Virtual Disk does nothing.

After finally getting it into Read Only mode some NTFS corruption errors are being reported:

> A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume S:.
>
> A corruption was found in a file system index structure.  The file
>   reference number is 0x10000001f44d3.  The name of the file is
>   "\Games\Steam\SteamApps\temp\304930\Maps\Washington\Foliage".  The
>   corrupted index attribute is ":$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".

But there is no way to fix them if the drive is stuck in Read Only.

Comment: Have you checked the cabling to the drives?

Comment: Hi there - yes i did, plus all drives pass an extensive Manufacturers disk test. So i think hardware wise and connection they are all good. i suspect the file system has a problem. Issue is i cannot run check disk against it

Comment: In my experience, the first three errors you posted are always caused by failures at the hardware level. In particular, the *delayed write failed* means the storage device refused to write data. You get the same error if you unplug a flash drive in the middle of a write operation.

Comment: Running chkdsk is the wrong tool to try to fix this problem. You need to solve the issue with why the storage pool is degraded. Forcing this could destroy your data. Chkdsk runs at the file system level, not the physical disk / RAID level. For changing read/write mode see here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14861.modifying-a-storage-pool-that-has-a-read-only-configuration.aspx

Comment: Thank you both for the input.... im not sure what hardware problem can exist if the drives pass the manufacturers extended test and also can mount in read only mode. if i try and bring the pool into to Read / Write mode then it hangs whilst flatlining the disk for 15 mins....whilst i guess it scans the file systems then reports those NTFS errors and then goes offline. My only solution is to somehow find another system to copy all my data off and then to recreate the storage space and copy back.